# How to make onTouch do nothing with Action_up

Tags: java, android

I am making an app to control a toy car using my smart phone and arduino, i managed to connect to the bluetooth and module and test with an LED lights and everything is fine. I only have one concern, supposedly i want the car to move forward from on Touch method, like this code (but this one is for LED light)

```
LED_On.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                LEDOn();
                return true;
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                LEDOff();
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Now my problem is that i want a method or a technique to make the app do nothing when i remove my hand from the touch screen, because right now i am making a separate method for each Action_Down and Action_UP, which makes me specify a different letter each time to send to the arduino to make the changes in the toy car, and by doing so i will have tons of letters which is not convenient.

```
public void LEDOn(){
    // turn LED On
    if (btSocket!=null)
    {
        try
        {
            btSocket.getOutputStream().write("F".toString().getBytes());
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            msg("Error");
        }
    }
}
```

Also if someone can explain how does multitouch works exactly, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: what are the letters for?

Comment: i send the letters to arduino by bluetooth, to perform the commands on the arduino when i click any button i desire. For example: If I click on the forward button, i send 'F' and the arduino code receives it and starts the motors and the car moves forward. What i want to do is that when i remove my hand from the touch screen, i want to stop sending the signal 'F' with a method rather than making my app send another letter like 'f' to stop the car from moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing the same problem with making an Rc controller that was my approach to fix it.

I used this code to send z character whenever i am doing an Action up, for example i touched the forward button and then released, when i release i will send z character.

```
if(btSocket!=null){
        try
        {
            btSocket.getOutputStream().write("z".toString().getBytes());
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            msg("Error");
        }
    }
```

This is the method for my backward onTouch.

```
downView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                downOn();
                return true;
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                directionsOff();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

This is the method to send character D

```
public void downOn(){
    // starts moving backwards
    if(btSocket!=null){
        try
        {
            btSocket.getOutputStream().write("D".toString().getBytes());
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            msg("Error");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the arduino code i used, i was testing on LEDs.

```
if (state == 'D') {
  digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
}else if (state == 'F') {
  digitalWrite(LED2, HIGH);
}else{
  digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
}
```

I hope i made it clear enough.